# How to remove only opening and closing bracket from a string in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a string like this:

**(1/8in Cap TBE ASME B1.20.1 (NPT) Male x Fem CL400 CU Alloy B152 Gr C10400 Cement Lined)**

I need output like this:

**1/8in Cap TBE ASME B1.20.1 (NPT) Male x Fem CL400 CU Alloy B152 Gr C10400 Cement Lined**

i.e. only remove the brackets at the start and end not in the middle.

Also
if the string is like this, either having starting bracket or closing bracket

**(1/8in Cap TBE ASME B1.20.1 (NPT) Male x Fem CL400 CU Alloy B152 Gr C10400 Cement Lined**

or

**1/8in Cap TBE ASME B1.20.1 (NPT) Male x Fem CL400 CU Alloy B152 Gr C10400 Cement Lined)**

then don't remove the brackets.

I tried using regexp_replace but couldn't find the solution.
Any help will be appreciable

Comment: What about strings like xxx(x(x)x)xxx?  Or it's just required to delete first and last symbols from string if both this symbols are "brackets"?

Comment: only need to remove those brackets present at the first and last position

Answer (score 3):

As simple `CASE` is enough to remove the *leading* and *ending* brackets

```
with txt as (
select '(xxxx)' txt from dual union all
select '(x(x)xx)' txt from dual union all
select '(xxxx' txt from dual union all
select 'xxxx)' txt from dual union all
select 'xxxx' txt from dual)
select txt,
case when txt like '(%)' then 
    substr(txt,2,length(txt)-2)
else
   txt
end as new_txt
from txt
```

gives

```
TXT      NEW_TXT
-------- --------
(xxxx)   xxxx     
(x(x)xx) x(x)xx   
(xxxx    (xxxx    
xxxx)    xxxx)    
xxxx     xxxx
```

Alternatively you may use `REGEXP` as follows

```
select 
  txt,
  nvl(
     REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '^\((.*)\)$', 1, 1, null, 1),
     txt)
  as txt_new
from txt
```

The regexp `'^\((.*)\)$'` enforced the leading and trailing bracket and returns the part between - first group (the fifth parameter of REGEXP_SUBSTR).

In case the REGEXP_SUBSTR return noting, i.e. there expression is *not enclosed in brackets* the `NVL` return the original value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to use this at multiple places, writing case statement everywhere won't be recommended

Comment: @ShashankJha added a regexp solution, but you'll need some expression logik to get rid of the brackets.You mey define a function if you need to minimize the coding.